# Yii Dynamic DB Connection according to user with master database

Tags: database, yii, multi-tenant

My project is on the basis of multi-tenent SaaS.

I have multiple clients (companies) and each client has multiple users - they all will use the same database layout.

Each client has their own database, so during user authentication, I want to Build a master database that associates the user with a company database for that user.

The structure of each database is identical... only the data is different.

So that we can keep the different database for the different company, that will not going to mix in data in database.

The number of clients (and therefor the number of databases) is unknown when the application is written, so it is not possible to include all the connections in the bootstrap script.

Now, what I want to do is, dynamically alter the DB connection that is in the bootstrap or have the ability to dynamically create a new connection for the user signing in. Is there a simple solution for this in Yii and still use AR , query builder ?

I saw this solution but not working for me http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/5385-dynamic-db-connection/

This is how my config file looks today for the script running one database, i want to call a master database that controls which database the user belongs to and the app uses in Yii, any idea?

```
<? php

 $language = 'en'; 

  $currencyBaseCode = 'USD';

 $theme = 'default';

 $connectionString = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=master';

 $username = 'root';

 $password = 'YOUR PASS';

 $memcacheServers = array( // An empty array means memcache is not used.

 array(

'host' => '127.0.0.1',

'port' => 11211, // This is the default memcached port.


 'weight' => 100,

  ),

  );

  $adminEmail = 'EMAIL ADDRESS';

  $installed = true; // Set to true by the installation process.

  $maintenanceMode = false; // Set to true during upgrade process or other maintenance tasks.

  $instanceConfig = array(); //Set any parameters you want to have merged into configuration array.

  //@see CustomManagement

  $instanceConfig['components']['request']['hostInfo'] = 'website url';

  $instanceConfig['components']['request']['scriptUrl'] = '/app/index.php';

  $urlManager = array (); // Set any parameters you want to customize url manager. 
  ? >
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the master database in the config file, and use the normal AR class to connect to it to retrieve the credentials. Then, close the connection.

Then [extend the AR class, specifically the `getDbConnection()` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/5385-dynamic-db-connection/). Get the relevant credentials, and pass them as a parameters to a new CDbConnection object.

The initial DB request to get the credentials is going to be a huge performance drag, so you should really store them in-memory with Redis or Memcached. Yii doesn't do that natively.

There are a few different ways around this:

- Different front controllers loading different config files, each of which is dynamically generated or destroyed by a separate app.
- One big database. Each record has a key to define which client it belongs to.
- One big database. Tables can be duplicated by using a client name as part of the table name.

None of these will be easy with Yii, as this is not really something Yii was designed to do.

Comment: But can it just make a master database with User, pass, email, databasename and when people logon it points to the databasename colom to find the database? and user/pass for authentication? i am a bit lost :)

Comment: @JesperQvist Yes, you can do that, but it will be a huge hit on performance that you should avoid. If you store the credentials in Redis it will be much, much quicker to access the relevant client database.

Comment: so i install Redis and make that as the master database, how do you suggest i make the change from there, hard or simple task?

Comment: @JesperQvist Fairly easy, using phpredis (or predis). If the client goes to client1.example.com, use `client1` as the Redis key for a hash containing the database credentials. Use a separate CRUD for the database admin to manage the client credentials. In the extended `getDbConnection()` method, make the call to Redis to get the has based on the subdomain key.

Comment: Okay, got it so each client need a subdomain then... i was thinking about one master login like app.domain . com but your method would change that methodology i assume... i am not hardcore in this that is why i am trying to get as much help as possible, persistant want to figure it out though :)

Comment: Different subdomain per client is definitely a good idea. It's an easy way to load balance, for example - just point different subdomains at different servers.

Comment: i forgot to tell you this is hosted with Amazon EC2 so i will juts add more servers on the go that is why i prefer a main login domain